# How to define welcome file list in spring 4 using java config annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load welcome file using spring java config annotation. I read some document from google and got idea if I used index.html or index.jsp into our webcontent folder then it will load automatically. But I am using login.jsp page.

So it not loaded automatically.

I have tried to loaded login.jsp file using below code but unable to load.

My attempt :

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Every time I am getting 404 exception. What I am missing?

Below Image showing the place of login.jsp

[image]

Comment: can you please provide location of your login.jsp ?

Comment: Added the image. Please check.

Comment: login.jsp should be in `/WEB-INF/views/` as you defined in InternalResourceViewResolver.

Comment: I have also placed my login.jsp into /WEB-INF/views/ location but still its not working.

Comment: Can you confirm that the DispatcherServlet is mapped to `/`?

Comment: Dispatcher servlet mapped into "/forms/*", "/rest/*"